# Reading SOAP Header and Body elements

Tags: c#, soap

I want to read elements value like  from soap header  and  from SOAP Body .      Please look into the code below and help me out to fetch custid and clientid form header and body. Post me if you need any further clarification

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
   <APHeader xmlns="http://www.test.com/es/v1/ws">
    <usr>
    <Verb>Set</Verb>
    <Noun>ProcessEIACMPermissions</Noun>
    <DataVer>001:000</DataVer>
    <SrcAppID xsi:type="xsd:string">AP</SrcAppID>
    <CustID>30081241</CustID>
    <APMsgCorrelationID>00000000000000000000000000000000</APMsgCorrelationID>
    </usr>
  </APHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessEIACMPermissionsRequest      xmlns="http://www.adp.com/es/ezlm/v1/schema/tlmclientconfiguration">
    <ClientID>30081241</ClientID>
  </ProcessEIACMPermissionsRequest>
 </soap:Body>
```

Comment: Any reason you are fiddling in the XML of a SOAP message instead of using the object model of the toolkit (WebServices)?

Comment: This is the request i get from the client in this format. I don't have any other choice

Comment: Of course you have a choice in HOW to use the SOAP message. You can use an X(ml)Document and go the hardcore way, you can use WCF channel/service-layer, you can use XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, SoapFormatter. So many options. Why is the client sending you SOAP in the first place? WebServices! Use a WebServices toolkit! (WCF or WebAPI for Asp.Net)

Comment: Thanks marvin for your suggestion. Can you help me out to understand which of the simplest way i can use to read SOAP header and Body element like custID value  Client ID value. Please send me some example on the basis of above file i sent.

Comment: Set up a webservice (i would choose WCF for this) which accepts the message type from the customer (exposes an endpoint), then use the object model in the WS implementation to access the properties of the message (pseudo: Msg.Headers[x].ClientID)

Comment: Simply set up a web service using the WSDL file that the client provided. There are automated tools for this (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905(v=vs.110).aspx) which are used by Visual Studio and others. You can then create an easy web service client and get everything you need in serialized classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:

                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                foreach (SoapHeader header in message.Headers)
                {
                    if (header.GetType() == typeof(RouteInformation))
                    {
                        routeHdr = (RouteInformation) header;
                        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeHdr.ConsumerID))
                            id = DataFix.FixInt(routeHdr.ID);
                    }
                    else if (header.GetType() == typeof (Header))
                    {
                        Hdr = (Header) header;
                        Custid = DataFix.FixInt(Hdr.m_objUsr.ID);

                    }
                    else if(header.GetType() == typeof(Configuration))
                    {
                        configHdr = (ConfigurationAPHeader) header;

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the simple way to do so. Just Read the inputstream from httprequest,load the xml and get the CustID from xml. Below is the code for same.

```
 var httpApp = sender as HttpApplication;
            var Request = httpApp.Request as HttpRequest;
            string documentContents;
            using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }            
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.LoadXml(documentContents);
            XmlElement root = xd.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList titleList = root.GetElementsByTagName("CustID");
            return titleList[0].InnerText;
```